# Firebase SMS authentication is delayed or sometimes not received

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, sms

**ISSUE**

Firebase SMS authentication is delayed or sometimes not received

**QUESTION**

I want to know what would be the cause of such issue.

- Tried to receive authentication to available phones and we receive the authentication.
- Not all of the users experience the issue, but only for some.

  - Specific location: Adelaide, Glenelg South Australia
  - Date encountered: December 08, 2022

Comment: Hey, have you found any solution for this? I'm experiencing exactly the same!

Comment: Hi Kirill, I only read in some discussions, that it's most likely the mobile service provider. Cause we check on the status in firebase and there is no related issue indicated. https://status.firebase.google.com. Also I check on downdetector and there seems to be an issue with the mobile service providers.

Comment: @KirillLapshev can i ask, (not the number) the mobile service provider you use for testing and which part of Australia.

Comment: @KirillLapshev
I only use the online mobile number - Australia
https://sms24.me/en/numbers/61476857122

Comment: I'm not from Australia, I do live in Portugal, but here it was happening the same using different mobile providers, not only Portuguese ones, so we are changing to Twilio

Comment: For us it depends on the pricing they offer, cause in Google Phone Auth it is much cheaper than Twilio for Australia.

Google pricing => https://firebase.google.com/pricing
Twilio pricing => https://www.twilio.com/en-us/pricing

Comment: I hope with Firebase that they have a check to different providers (locations) whether their authentication can reach those servers. More users are using or transferring to other services because of lack of transparency/checks. 
This maybe expensive though.